# Is there a difference between the mansion and the hidden mansion?

Tags: luigis-mansion

In Luigi's Mansion, after you defeat the final boss, the "Hidden Mansion" is unlocked. But from the looks of it and the ghosts I am defeating, the hidden mansion is basically the same as the first mansion. Is there *any* difference between the two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on whether you are playing the PAL version of the game or not, different things may change.

**Things that change in all versions:**

- Ghosts do **double damage**
- The Poltergust 3000 is **1.5 times** as powerful, making it easier to get more money and therefore better frames

**Things that change in PAL versions:**

- The mansion is **mirrored horizontally**
- There are **more normal ghosts** around the mansion
- Bosses are more difficult, having different attacks
- Rooms are **much darker** (but only as dark as in the NTSC version - normally, the PAL version is brighter)
- Boos often have **increased HP**, though some have decreased
- **Fewer hearts** appear
- Speedy Spirits and Gold Mice always give up a Silver Diamond when caught, raising the maximum possible amount of money from 142,390,000G to 186,440,000G
- 45 rather than 40 Boos are required to fight the final boss
- Boos are faster and more difficult to catch
- Five ghosts rather than three appear in The Artist's Studio

To read more in-depth and look through sources, see [here](http://www.mariowiki.com/Luigi%27s_Mansion#Hidden_Mansion).

Comment: PAL? What does that mean? And what is NTSC?

Comment: @JerryRox PAL, NTSC and SECAM are three different analog TV standards (ways to represent video) that are used around the world. NTSC is used mostly in the US, and PAL mostly in Europe.

When it comes to games - consoles are made to either work with NTSC TVs or PAL TVs. This makes some consoles and games have regional differences - not tied to the cuntry itself, but the video standard.

Even nowadays, with analogue TV dying, the same regions are often enforced when it comes to release dates, region locks, localization and such.

Comment: @JerryRox The comments section markdown handicapping murdered my linebreaks, but the gist is different regions have different versions of games. The version of your game is most often displayed somewhere on the front of the box.

Comment: I play the North American Version. NTSC it is, then.